# Script to check for consecutive pattern in a file

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling

I need to write a script that looks thru the file and if the following pattern :"ERROR:  could not obtain lock" occurs CONSECUTIVE X amount of times to send out an email.

I have written one that scans the file and sends an email if it sees an occurence, could I get some help in modifying it to only alert if the pattern is seen lets say 5 times in a row

```
if grep -q ERROR:  could not obtain lock "error.txt"; then
  echo “check the server” | mail -s "5 consecutive errors" test@test.com 
fi
```

I tried doing it with uniq but it outputs number of occurences whenever it happens

```
cat error.file | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | grep 'ERROR' | awk '{print $1}'
2
5
```

Below is contents of the error.file

```
    ERROR
    ERROR
    12345
    ERROR
    ERROR
    ERROR
    ERROR
    ERROR
```

I need it to produce output only if it finds 5 consecutive matches in a row and ignore anything under 5.

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will send mail every time it sees at least 5 consecutive errors so it can send multiple mails if 5 consecutives ERROR happens multiple time

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /ERROR/){n_error+=1}else{n_error=0}}; n_error==5{system("echo \"check the server\" | mail -s \"5 consecutive errors\" test@test.com")}' error.txt
```

This one exits as soon as mail is sent :

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /ERROR/){n_error+=1}else{n_error=0}}; n_error==5{system("echo \"check the server\" | mail -s \"5 consecutive errors\" test@test.com"); exit 0}' error.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first get all the line numbers where the `grep` gets a match and store them in an array.
Next define a counter to count the number of consecutive hits.
Then loop through the array and count the number of consecutive hits. If it reaches 5 then send the email and break out of the loop.

Don't know if it is the most efficient answer, but it seems to work quite well.

```
#!/bin/bash

consecutiveHits=0
foo=( $(grep -n <Pattern> <File> | cut -f1 -d: | sort -u) )
prevNum=${foo[0]}
for i in "${foo[@]:1}"
do
    if [ $i = $((prevNum+1)) ]
    then
        ((consecutiveHits++))
    else
        consecutiveHits=0
    fi

    if [ $consecutiveHits = 5 ]
    then
        echo “check the server” | mail -s "5 consecutive errors" test@test.com 
        break
    fi
    prevNum=$i
done
```